# OpenStack upgrade with minimal downtime with 2 nodes

Tags: openstack

I'm looking for a solution on how to upgrade 2 `OpenStack` nodes with minimal downtime of running virtual machines.

Our current situation is that we have one node working as controller with about 50 live virtual machines running on it.

We have second server with the same HW specification as the one with running OpenStack (Same blade in blade cluster). This used to be a `VMware` server but last year we continously migrated all virtual machines to OpenStack.

We can install the second node to be either controller or compute node.

My research is focused on what's the best way to upgrade to higher version with minimal downtime of live virtual machines. 
Any suggestions please? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should have no downtime on your Virtual Machines when upgrading OpenStack. The OpenStack services can be restarted at anytime and should only affect API requests. The only potential impact on running virtual machines would be if you need to update something like OVS or the Operating System (includes things like kvm).

Comment: How about upgrading of a service like Neutron or Nova. Don't the instances lose the connectivity or get suspended for a time of upgrade?

Comment: Nova won't do anything, and at worst with Neutron you will see a little blip in the network traffic, but in general the users should not notice the upgrade. You may want to make sure your dhcp leases are long enough to handle a neutron upgrade.

Comment: Ideally try this out in a lab environment of course before trying to do it in production.